# Java Generic - object method cannot be found

Tags: java, generics, immutability

I've an interface that looks like:

```
package com.sample.service;

import com.sample.model.Request;

public interface Service<T> {
    void add(T domain);
    <E> boolean update(Request<E> request);
}
```

Where the Request.java

```
package com.sample.model;

public class Request<E> {
    private final E entity;

    public Request(E entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public E getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
}
```

The following is my implementation

```
package com.sample.service;

import com.sample.domain.User;
import com.sample.model.Form;
import com.sample.model.Request;

public class UserServiceImpl implements Service<User> {

    @Override
    public  void add(User user) {
        System.out.println("add: " + user);
    }

    @Override
    public <Form> boolean update(Request<Form> request) {
        System.out.println("update: " + request);
        Form form = request.getEntity();
        //form.setUsername("some_username");//This line caused compile error
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here are the Form.java

```
package com.sample.model;

public class Form {
    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return username;
    }
}
```

and User.java

```
package com.sample.domain;

public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

When I compiled and execute these codes everything is fine. However, when I uncomment the line commented in UserServiceImpl, I got compile error

```
UserServiceImpl.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        form.setUsername("some_username");
```

My question is why the setUsername method in form object cannot be found? The form object is mutable.

Comment: Does E accept any other type except Form? Did you replace E with Form and try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the method `setUsername` is not being recognised is explained in the answer of Arkadiy. However there are other issues with your code.

In the interface

```
public interface Service<T> {
    void add(T domain);
    <E> boolean update(Request<E> request);
}
```

`E` is allowed to be any type. You should not try to implement `update` in the concrete class by insisting that `request` be of type `Request<Form>` because then the `update` method has a different signature.

One solution would be to make the interface have two parameters

```
public interface Service<T, E> {
    void add(T domain);
    boolean update(Request<E> request);
}
```

Then you would need

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements Service<User, Form>
```

The signature of the `update` method in the concrete class should be

```
public boolean update(Request<Form> request)
```

because the method is *not* generic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, by moving the E from method to the type level, I can access the form object setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 6):

In your code

```
public <Form> boolean update(Request<Form> request)
```

`Form` is not `com.sample.model.Form`. Instead, it's another generic parameter, just like `E` in

```
<E> boolean update(Request<E> request);
```

. Compiler knows nothing about `E` even if you happen to give it a name that coincides with a name of one of real classes. The only thing compiler can be sure about `E` (or `Form` in that same context) is that it's an `Object` instance. And `Object` does not have any `getEntity` methods.

If you're coming from C++ background, you're attempting an explicit  specialization of a template. However, Java generics are not templates. They do not generate code. They only provide some compile-time checking and run-time typecasts (there is a bit more, but not much). Look up "[type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)" in the context of Java Generics.

To implement a more useful solution, you could try to decide what sort of interface an argument to `update()` has to have. If there is a required interface, write it up as a Java `interface` and use as the argument type. If there is not (rare case), you can still use empty `interface` for labeling purposes, but you need to upcast the argument yourself - assuming `UserServiceImpl` knows what type is passed to `update()`.

In ether case, the generics are likely not needed in update().

Comment: You beat me by 3 seconds. (+1) for speed!

Comment: May I suggest adding a bit more of an explanation?  For someone new to type erasure, more of an explanation is needed, imho.

Comment: I'd also add that the solution is simply to get rid of the first `<Form>`.

Comment: I'll go slower next time :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. If I replace the Request E (remove the generic) with Object, then cast it to Form when I call the getEntity method, is this a good solution ?

Comment: @SteveP. - I tried to add more. Please feel free to edit if you think still more (or different) clarification is needed.

Comment: @Arkadiy: Actually, the request.getEntity() is fine in compilation as well as execution. The problem is I can't access the method inside the form object returned by this line. I've tried to print out the form object type and it turned out to be "class com.sample.model.Form". So, I still can access those methods through reflection but it's a bit hacky.

Comment: You don't need to use reflection - you can cast. However - try to avoid that and give that work to the compiler. Paul Boddington's solution is one possibility.